# Silverstripe relation is not visible on details page

Tags: php, silverstripe

Am looping teachers relation on template `CoursePage.ss` but when i try to loop that relation `teachers` inside `CouresePage_details.ss` does not work. Am doing somthing wrong.

I have two models `Courses` and `Teachers`

1. `Course` can have many teachhers
2. `Teacher` can have one course

**Courses.php**

```
class Courses extends DataObject 
{
     private static $many_many = array(
        'Teachers' => 'Teachers',
    );
}
```

**Teachers.php**

```
class Courses extends DataObject 
{
     private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Courses ' => 'Courses ',
    );
}
```

**CoursesPage.php**

```
class CoursesPage extends Page
{

}

class CoursesPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
    public static $allowed_actions = array(
        'details'
    );

    // Show specific course

    public function details(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
    {
        $c= Courses::get()->byID($request->param('ID'));

        if(!$c) {
            return $this->httpError(404, "Courses not found");
        }

        return array(
            'Courses' => $c,
        );
    }

    // Courses list

    public function CoursesList ()
    {
       $c = Courses::get()->sort('Featured', 'DESC');

        return $c;
     }
}
```

**CoursesPage.ss**

In this file i just loop courses, nothing important. Here i loop list of courses and teachers. Here teachers looping working perfect just not work on details template.

**CoursesPage_details.ss**

Here is problem. When i show details about specific `course` i want to loop `teachers` which is related with this course but i all time get `NULL` return `Teachers does not exist` . Looks like it is not in scope.

```
<section class="course-details">
    <h2>$Courses.Name</h2> <!-- Work -->
    <p>$Courses.Descr</p>

    <ul class="teachers-list">
        <% if $Teachers %> <!-- Not work here, but on CoursePage.ss work -->
            <% loop $Teachers %>
                 $FirstName
            <% end_loop %>
        <% else >
           Teachers does not exist
        <% end_if %>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$Courses.Teachers` instead… or you could just change the scope to Courses, by using `<% with $Courses %>`. So your template would look like this:

```
<section class="course-details">
<% with $Courses %>
    <h2>$Name</h2>
    <p>$Descr</p>

    <ul class="teachers-list">
        <% if $Teachers %> 
            <% loop $Teachers %>
                 $FirstName
            <% end_loop %>
        <% else >
           Teachers does not exist
        <% end_if %>
    </ul>
<% end_with %>
</section>
```

The reason for this is: You're passing your `Course` DataObject to the template as a parameter named `Courses`. It's this DataObject that has a relation to Teachers, therefore you need to use `$Courses.Teachers` or change the scope as outlined above. 
By default, you're still in the scope of `CoursesPage`.